# Error with Custom Action in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

I'm very new in C# world though I'm trying to modify an installer using custom action. What I'm trying to do is to run a batch script after installation finishes. I'm using the following Installer class:

```
namespace PostInstall
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class Installer1 : Installer
    {
        public Installer1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("PostInstall.bat");
        }
    }
}
```

A project named PostInstall contains a *.cs file with the code above. The project is created following [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#Y444)'s section "To create the custom action". In the setup project, I've added the primary output of PostInstall project in Install & Commit node as described in the link.

Yet at the end of the installation the following error is received:

> Error 1001. Unable to create an instance PostInstall.Installer1
>   installer type -> Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation. -> The system can't find the file specified.

I verified that `PostInstall.bat` exists in the installation directory. Why the error is occurring and how to resolve it?

Comment: Why don't you call PostInstall.bat on Committed event?

Comment: then i get another error. my idea is if the constructor is called then the batch should be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the installation directory is not automatically the directory in which the installer is run, so you cannot assume that `Process.Start("PostInstall.bat")` will find the batch file.

[This DevCity article](http://devcity.net/Articles/339/1/article.aspx) is a very good introduction to this topic, and tells you how to get the installation directory passed to your custom action objects so that you can create the full pathname for your batch file.

Have you thought about what will happen while your batch file is running? Do you want to wait until it is finished before proceeding to the next stage of your installation?

Comment: the batch file just changes the installation directory's privilege. i assumed that the batch fill will be called from installation directory. it is copied there by the installer.

Comment: @Donotalo - hope that helped, and if you learned that "I assumed" is one of the most dangerous phrases in the world that will help you even more in future!

Comment: i've replaced the whole technique. i've c, c++ & win32 background. i replaced the custom action with a c++ program and added that in the commit node of the setup project. it worked. :) the link is terrible and thank you for sharing it. i've learned a lot in the process. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the custom actions should be written in native code, if it's not possible in your case try to run the .msi as Administrator